# I looking for a "universal" automatic volume control for any of my devices how to do that?

Tags: amplifier, audio, programmable-gain-amplifier

I looking for a “universal” automatic volume control  for any of my devices, how to do that?

**Context:**

I mean I can connect it between a pc, a tv, a tablet or anything and a speaker.
Whatever I do :  increasing or decreasing sound volume on entry, the speaker still produce the same sound volume.

I've been reading for a few hours now, about AGC & AVC *(automatic gain control & automatic volume control)* ; but this doesn't seem to fit this need.

**First idea :**
A solution might be to use a mic to compare ambient sound volume to automatically reduce/increase it. But this will not work if I prefer to use a headphone instead of a speaker. **So I rejected that solution.**

I m looking for a solution like :

```
 input side : if sound volume increase on that device, output sound volume remain the same
 input side : if sound volume decrease on that device, output sound volume remain the same 
 output must be a jack to be able to use any kind of devices, external amplifier, headphones, speakers and so on.
```

**Something like that block diagram :**

[image]

For the final stage before output I think using a simple band pass filter & standard LM386 audio amplifier, & finally the output jack connector.

But I don't find/understand how to make the “check signal” & adjustment of the “positive”, “negative gain” blocks in the schema.
It could be some sort of comparator but a comparator to a voltage one ?
Something else ? And then how to adapt gain to be positive or negative ? Potentiometers IC's ?

**The real question then is**
How can I design the “check signal” & its adjustment to the “positive”, “negative gain” blocks of the schema ?

Any more detailed diagram block, IC references, or better ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: It's trivial to measure the voltage on the headphones from which you can calculate the loudness, but determining if sound is low because the volume is low or because you simply have a quiet part (e.g. gaps between songs) may not be. If you do this naively you are going to spike the volume every time the track or program changes. If you can solve that, fees your results into the gain setting on an amplifier.

Comment: Any solution needs to know what is the source and where control can be made and what inputs are possible to perform an algorithm on. i.e. Need a spec

Comment: That is just exactly what I want to avoid  @TonyStewartEE75  I really mean the output average volume is constant whatever, the average volume is at input.

Comment: How do you define volume staying the same? Very not trivial thing for complex audio stream! If you average, then what is the rolling time window? Does this cover all your use cases? Exponential averaging and filtering is easier done on the entire sound file ahead of time, do you know the input ahead of time so that you can pre process ?. Mixing techniques like envelope shaping or amplitude compression may achieve the desired primary result at cost of fidelity of the loud parts or poor dynamic range, but this comes with the territory.

Comment: @user1850479, then is it an idea to check in with a  delay of few milliseconds (10/20) ?

Comment: Sure it's a great idea until you encounter a delay of 30ms, or 40ms, or the track has blank audio for intro, or a million things that you haven't thought of. This is called overconstraint.

Comment: @crasic  that is a good question , I don't really know, I think setting a voltage reference or something similar would to the trick about getting a constant output average volume. I am not audiophile so I can loose a very little fidelity. for the remaining remarks in your post, it just look chinese to me. I don't understand those technical names/expressions.

Comment: Once you can figure that out, then go ahead and update the question so that we at help you with your solution, we can't help with something that even you don't know what you want.

Comment: ok so I have to forget all about the project ? as far as it is impossible to know/estimate the input signal form/amplitude in advance ? or I did just misunderstood your meanings @crasic

Comment: I don't think you should forget about the project, it sounds like a great idea. Have you researched if there are any  available off the shelf options? have you tried any? For example, if they  are expensive, why? what about the technology would make it's so? If they don't exist, why? Maybe it isn't feasible economically with existing technology.   If it there were an easy obvious solution it would already be on Alibaba. Maybe they are, I don't know, it's not my project. If it were me I would use it as an opportunity to learn more and not invest too much into the outcome.

Comment: AGC exists. Have you ever heard a broadcast where the action has pauses? When the action ceases, the background noise, unnoticable at first, gets louder and louder and louder, and then with the next intentional noise from the players, the background noise suddenly ceases? That's called AGC 'breathing', and it's due to an AGC turning the gain up to 'keep the volume constant', but having a time constant unsuitable to the programme material. Solve the 'match the AGC algorithm to the source material' problem, perhaps with AI, and the world will beat a path to your door.

Comment: @francoisP Perhaps the better field of study will be hearing aids. $$$$ I would start by reading a modern paper from this year, 2021: $$$$ [Synchronized Automatic Gain Control in Bilateral Cochlear Implant Recipients Yields Significant Benefit in Static and Dynamic Listening Conditions](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8150445/) $$$$ and work myself backwards to this multi-cited one from 1988: $$$$ [A comparison of four methods of implementing automatic gain control (AGC) in hearing aids](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/3390637/) $$$$ They may help you improve your specifications.

Comment: Thanks @Neil_UK, I don't think it is easy enough to adapt, but interesting. I hope I'll be able to redefine my block diagram to something more usable & more related to a future nearly - schematic feature as a new start point for this project.

Answer (score 0):

AGC is defined by spectral BW, attack time , decay time, compression ratio and gain dynamic range , input/output gain and amplitudes and a few others specs missing with your question. Like crest factor, ambient noise suppression and signal/noise  gain improvement.  The algorithm will change with voice vs music and suppression of artifact noise with multiple acoustic sensors. While companders use dynamic compression and expansion. Constant level of noise then signal will cause fatigue.

Comment: thanks, for now I don't knwo what are all this things "attack time" "decay time," etc....  that's why I thougth it should be very easier to define a device.

Comment: I wish this site would link every technical word,  so you could easily look up the meaning, but this is how it's done, not your way.  Like Noise Spectrum https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Colors_of_noise. Even I learned something new "Green Noise" WHo would have thought of  this!!